# Get an average value of a property from a list of objects

Tags: python, oop

I have a class:

```
class Peak:
    def __init__(self):
        self.FileID = ""
        self.RT = 0
        self.Intensity = 0
        self.MZ = 0
        self.ChiSq = 0
```

I populate its properties and add it to a list but how do I get the average RT for example as a single value.

Comment: what exactly are you having problems with? Do you know how to calculate the average if you had a list of ints? Have you looked at `statistics.mean`? Do you know how to *access* an attribute? Do you know how to loop over a list? What have you tried and how does it not work?

Comment: In one of your comments, you asked about finding max.  There's a `max` function that works on lists.  Just use that instead of sum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume you have a list of instances of your class:

```
lst = [Peak(), Peak(), Peak(), ...]
```

and you've gone through and populated their attributes.  If you want to compute the average value of `RT` among all the instances in `lst`, you could do

```
lst_avg = sum([i.RT for i in lst]) / len(lst)
```

Answer (score 1):

**Simple as that! :)**

```
#python Code
sum = 0
count = 0
for objects in list:
    sum = sum + object.RT
    count = count + 1
avg = sum / count
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

If you have a list of `Peak` objects, in order to get the average RT of all of them, you should first create a list of the RT of each `Peak`, and calculate the average of that.

You can do it in a single line:

```
avg_rt = sum([item.RT for item in my_list]) / len(my_list)
```

Comment: Why did you copy my answer as your own?

Comment: I didn't, I wrote it and when I posted it (after I wrote mine and clicked Post) I noted yours... I even upvoted yours. I don't want to fight. I can delete it if you think it would be appropriate.

Comment: It wasn't ill intended, I assure you.

Comment: np.  It's good to look for the "new answers on this question" prior to submitting.

Comment: Thanks all now how do I get a max value from a property of  the same structure?